# How to implement a debounce time in keyup event in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I create an Angular app that search students from API. It works fine but it calls API every time an input value is changed. I've done a research that I need something called debounce ,but I don't know how to implement this in my app.

**App.component.html**

```
    <div class="container">
  <h1 class="mt-5 mb-5 text-center">Student</h1>
<div class="form-group">
  <input  class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" [(ngModel)]=q (keyup)=search() placeholder="Search student by id or firstname or lastname">
</div>
 <hr>
 <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">ID</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center" style="width: 30%;">Name</th>
       <th scope="col" style="width: 30%;">E-mail</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 30%;">Phone</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let result of results">
        <th scope="row">{{result.stu_id}}</th>
        <td>{{result.stu_fname}} {{result.stu_lname}}</td>
         <td>{{result.stu_email}}</td>
        <td>{{result.stu_phonenumber}}</td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {


  results;
  q = '';

  constructor(private http:Http) {


  }


  search() {
    this.http.get("https://www.example.com/search/?q="+this.q)
    .subscribe(
      (res:Response) => {
          const studentResult = res.json();
          console.log(studentResult);
          if(studentResult.success) {
            this.results = studentResult.data;
          } else {
            this.results = [];
          }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]

I've tried something like this but it's error 
**Property debounceTime does not exist on type Subject<{}>**

```
  mySubject = new Subject();
  constructor(private http:Http)  {
    this.mySubject
    .debounceTime(5000)
    .subscribe(val => {
      //do what you want
    });
  }
```

and this's also not work. **Property 'fromEvent' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'**

```
    Observable.fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(this.getNativeElement(this.term), 'keyup')
```

So, what's the correct way to implement this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the component you can do somthing like this.  Create RxJS `Subject`, In `search` method which is called on `keyup` event, do `.next()` on this `Subject` you have created. Then `subscribe` in `ngOnInit()` will `debounce` for 1 second, as in below code.

```
searchTextChanged = new Subject<string>();
constructor(private http:Http) {

}


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.searchTextChanged
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .mergeMap(search => this.getValues())
        .subscribe(() => { });
}

getValues() {
    return this.http.get("https://www.example.com/search/?q="+this.q)
    .map(
      (res:Response) => {
          const studentResult = res.json();
          console.log(studentResult);
          if(studentResult.success) {
            this.results = studentResult.data;
          } else {
            this.results = [];
          }
      }
    )
}

search($event) {
    this.searchTextChanged.next($event.target.value);
}
```

**rxjs v6 has several breaking changes including simplifying import points for operators. Try installing `rxjs-compat`, which adds back those import paths until the code has been migrated.**

Import the necessary operators from `RxJS`. Below ones are for RxJS 5.x

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
import "rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";
```

Comment: It's still get an error  **Property 'debounceTime' does not exist on type 'Subject<string>'**  at  `.debounceTime(1000)`   Here's my new code. [link](https://pastebin.com/N9NGywar)

Comment: @mongkonsrisin , rxjs v6 has several breaking changes including simplifying import points for operators. Try installing `rxjs-compat`, which adds back those import paths until the code has been migrated.

Comment: After installing rxjs-compat ,that error has gone , but there is another error at `this.getValues(search)`  **Expected 0 arguments, but got 1**

Comment: @mongkonsrisin , sorry about that, in `ngOnInit` `this.getValues(search)` should be `this.getValues()` as is it not expecting any arguments. I have updated the answer

Comment: It's still error **Argument of type '(search: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.**

Comment: @mongkonsrisin, yes, in `getValues()` we need to change `.subscribe` to `.map` and return the `Observable` by returning `this.http.get()` method. I have updated the `getValues()` method, take look.

Comment: Thank you @Basavaraj Bhusani , You help me a lot. :D Now, my app works very well.

Comment: Hi, can you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566582/observables-creating-a-mock-http-request). I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: perfect solution for KAVITA

Answer (score 12):

For anyone coming across this in a newer version of angular (and rxjs).

The new Rxjs has pipeable operators and they can be used like this (from the accepted answers code)

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.subscription = this.searchTextChanged.pipe(
   debounceTime(1000),
   distinctUntilChanged(),
   mergeMap(search => this.getValues())
  ).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

Also, you can use angular **formControls** to bind the input search field

```
<input  class="form-control form-control-lg" 
type="text" [formControl]="searchField"
placeholder="Search student by id or firstname or lastname">
```

and use **valueChanges** observable on our searchField to react to changes of out search field in your **App.component.ts** file.

```
searchField: FormControl; 

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchField.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(5000) 
      .subscribe(term => {
    // call your service endpoint.
      });
}
```

optionally you can use **distinctUntilChanged** ( which only publishes to its output stream if the value being published is different from the previous one)

```
searchField: FormControl; 

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchField.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(5000) 
     .distinctUntilChanged()
     .subscribe(term => {
            // call your service endpoint.
      });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using angular 6 and rxjs 6, try this:
Notice the `.pipe(debounceTime(1000))` before your `subscribe`

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';


search() {
    this.http.get("https://www.example.com/search/?q="+this.q)
    .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
    .subscribe(
      (res:Response) => {
          const studentResult = res.json();
          console.log(studentResult);
          if(studentResult.success) {
            this.results = studentResult.data;
          } else {
            this.results = [];
          }
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: This does not address the keyup event in any way

Comment: @Logus in the description of the questions, the guy asked that he needs to implement something called debounceTime but he doesn't know how to implement that.

Comment: @NadhirFalta, the title actually mentions that he wants to implement debounce time in keyup event.

Comment: @Logus that's what it said in the questions description: " I've done a research that I need something called debounce ,but I don't know how to implement this in my app."

Comment: This implementation is not complete, but the key piece in this answer `.pipe(debounceTime(1000))` combined with the accepted answer solved my issue

Comment: It certainly doesn't work, and the API is fired instantly.

Answer (score 3):

Just use like this, without RXJS.

It may call 'search()' function itself every keyups, but it does not call inside contents of the function(such as http connect) every time. Much simple solution.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  debounce:any;

  constructor(){}
  
  search(){
    clearTimeout(this.debounce);
    this.debounce = setTimeout(function(){
      // Your Http Function..
    },500); // Debounce time is set to 0.5s
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Demo [Link](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/Angular/Angular7/NG7DebounceTime/)**

**Tutorial Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-add-debounce-time-using-rxjs-6-x-x-to-optimize-search-input-for-api-results-from-server/)**

[image]

**Using Template Variable**

```
<input type="text" #movieSearchInput class="form-control" placeholder="Type any movie name" />

    ...
    ...    
        fromEvent(this.movieSearchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
        // get value
        map((event: any) => {
            return event.target.value;
        })
        // if character length greater then 2
        ,filter(res => res.length > 2)
        // Time in milliseconds between key events
        ,debounceTime(1000)        
        // If previous query is diffent from current   
        ,distinctUntilChanged()
        // subscription for response
        ).subscribe((text: string) => {
            this.isSearching = true;
            this.searchGetCall(text).subscribe((res)=>{
            console.log('res',res);
            this.isSearching = false;
            this.apiResponse = res;
            },(err)=>{
            this.isSearching = false;
            console.log('error',err);
            });
        });
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: First, the @ViewChild was undefined on my ngOnInit() method. So I added the whole fromEvent on my ngAfterViewInit(). However, when I type in my input, in the first keyup my subscribe event is called only in the first type and is not called when I type again.

Answer (score 1):

user.component.html

```
   <input type="text" #userNameRef class="form-control"  name="userName" >  <!-- template-driven -->
 <form [formGroup]="regiForm"> 
      email: <input formControlName="emailId"> <!-- formControl -->
    </form>
```

user.component.ts

```
       import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
       import { switchMap,debounceTime, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


        @Component({
          selector: 'app-user',
          templateUrl: './user.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
        })
        export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

          constructor(private userService : UserService) { }


             @ViewChild('userNameRef') userNameRef : ElementRef;

             emailId = new FormControl(); 
   regiForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      emailId: this.bookId
   });   

             ngOnInit() {

                    fromEvent(this.userNameRef.nativeElement,"keyup").pipe(
                    debounceTime(3000),
                    map((userName : any) =>userName.target.value )
                  ).subscribe(res =>{
                    console.log("User Name is :"+ res);

                  } );
    //--------------For HTTP Call------------------

                  fromEvent(this.userNameRef.nativeElement,"keyup").pipe(
                    debounceTime(3000),
                    switchMap((userName : any) =>{
                   return this.userService.search(userName.target.value)
                 })
                  ).subscribe(res =>{
                    console.log("User Name is :"+ res);

                  } );



----------
                // For formControl 

                  this.emailId.valueChanges.pipe(
                  debounceTime(3000),
                  switchMap(emailid => {
                         console.log(emailid);
                        return this.userService.search(emailid);
                        })
                         ).subscribe(res => {
                               console.log(res);
                                    });


            }
```

***Note: make sure that your input element is not present in *ngIf Block.***