# Observables: Creating a mock http request

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to test my front-end code without the back-end api using observables.
In my component's template I have a textarea. Ultimately I need to send the textarea content to back-end api using http.post and receive back the validation for the content.

In the constructor of my component.ts I define an observable which does some very basic checks and creates mock results after a timeout of 2000ms (like http.post/http.get):

```
private obsVal: Observable < any >;
private obsChange: Observable < any >;

constructor() {

   this.obsVal = Observable.create(observer => {

       setTimeout(() => {
          let errorInfo = {};
          let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

          if (val < 6) {
              errorInfo['error'] = true;
              errorInfo['info'] = "Error! Unknown expression encountered.";
          } else {
              errorInfo['error'] = false;
          }
          observer.next(errorInfo);

      }, 1000)
  });
```

On any change inside the textarea the following function is called (creating another observable and subscribing to it):

```
textarea.on('change', () => {
     this.obsChange = Observable.create(observer => {
             observer.next("some text inside textarea");
             })

     this.obsChange.pipe(
         debounceTime(400),
         distinctUntilChanged(),
         switchMap((text) => {
             return this.obsVal
         })
     )
     .subscribe(errorResp => {
         this.addPanel(errorResp)
     });
  })
```

`addPanel` adds a DOM element in document to show the response.

I have used debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged  and switchMap so that only the latest request is rendered if the user types continuously. **However, it seems that these operators in pipe are not working as i'm receiving all the responses one after another.**

Surely I'm making some big conceptual mistake here. Can somebody please point it out?

**Note:** The textarea element is created dynamically inside the component so i can't access `(change)="doSomething()"` event on this.

**Update:**
I tried to update my code like this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/50276068/6188402).

Rather than passing the subscribe on every change, I created a subject and called its subscription in ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit() {
this.subscription = this.obsChange.pipe( //obsChange is  the subject
             debounceTime(400),
             distinctUntilChanged(),
             switchMap((text) => {
                 return this.obsVal
             })
         )
         .subscribe(errorResp => {
             this.addPanel(errorResp)
         });
}
```

And on change event, rather than creating a new obsChange observable I call next() to existing one:

```
textarea.on('change', () => {
         this.obsChange.next("some text");
      })
```

This works for the first time, but on further changes next() is called but it doesn't trigger obsChange in ngOnInit().

Comment: I guess the `.on('change', ...)` is not being piped, try changing it to use `(change)="yourMethod()"`, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276068/6188402

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. The textarea is created dynamically in the component.ts, so i don't have   access to (change) on it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Create `obsChange` only once right after dynamically inserting the textarea. Change your event handler to: `('change', () => this.obsChange.next(textarea.html()))`... its just a try

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes nope still doesn't work

Comment: To figure out what’s going on inside your observable chain, put ‘tap()’s at each point along the way and console.log what is going on.