# How to SetTimeout KeyUp in Angular 7

Tags: angular, settimeout, delay, angular7

I've searched solution in Google but not found.

**Tried 1:**

```
<input type="text" #txtSearch (keyup)="onKeyUp(txtSearch.value)">
```

And search.component.ts

```
onKeyUp(val){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(val);
    },500);
}
```

**Tried 2**

I'm using similar here [How to achieve a debounce service on input keyup event in angular2 with rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935424/how-to-achieve-a-debounce-service-on-input-keyup-event-in-angular2-with-rxjs) but in Angular 7 not working.

**Finally**

**I expect keyup  delay 0.5s then console.log(value);**

Comment: Should work. If not, please provide a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: See this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275945/how-to-implement-a-debounce-time-in-keyup-event-in-angular-6/50276294

Answer (score 6):

For such kind of cases, you can better to use `debounceTime` from `rxJs`. Even has much better support with angular. Have a look below with example -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { of, timer, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounce, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  model: string;
  modelChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {
        this.modelChanged.pipe(
            debounceTime(500))
            .subscribe(model => {
              console.log(model);
            });
    }

    changed(text: string) {
        this.modelChanged.next(text);
    }
}

<input [ngModel]='model' (ngModelChange)='changed($event)' />
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4znwkc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)